# Google ML Engine Jobs Differ in Accuracy between Standard and Premium ScaleTier

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm new to Machine Learning. I ran two similar ML jobs that only differed in the config.yaml file for GCP, specifically `scaleTier:`. Ran the first job with just `scaleTier: STANDARD_1` and got an accuracy of around 93%. Take the same Tensorflow records and adjusted the scaleTier to `scaleTier: PREMIUM_1` and the accuracy drops down to around 50%. Does increasing the number of ML Training Units decrease the accuracy of the model?

Two questions to this problem: Why does the accuracy drop considerably, and what are the work arounds to it?

Comment: Can you share more details such as: how many steps you ran it for, what was your batch_size, etc?

Comment: @rhaertel80 sure thing: number_threads=10, num_shards=10, num_samples=20000 , balanced_samples=5000. Used these details for both scaleTier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when you do distributed training, you should use smaller batch sizes. Can you try reducing your batch size to 1/8 of what you used in standard? You will have to increase your steps by 8x to make sure you are going through the dataset the same number of times.

Comment: Ah alright, i'll go ahead and try that. Thank you for this input

Comment: That did the trick, it definitely increase in accuracy when reducing the batch size. Thank you very much!